# placeholder default value Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml

Hi programming friends,

So i'm a newbie Symfony user having this problem where i get a 404 error when trying to get to my homepage.

This is my **../../../Resources/config/routing.yml** :

```
pl_if_soc_home:
    path:      /{page}
    defaults:
        _controller: PLIfsocBundle:Intervenant:index
        page:        1
    requirements:
        page: \d*
```

My **app/config/routing.yml** :

```
pl_ifsoc:
    resource: "@PLIfsocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /ifsoc
```

My **Controller** :

```
public function indexAction($page)
{
    if($page < 1)
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page "'.$page.'"inexistante.');
    }

    $nbPerPage = 5;

    $listInters = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('PLIfsocBundle:Intervenant')
            ->myFindAll($page, $nbPerPage);

    $nbPages = ceil(count($listInters)/$nbPerPage);

    if($page > $nbPages)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException("La page ".$page." n'existe pas.");
    }

    return $this->render('PLIfsocBundle:Intervenant:index.html.twig', array('listInters' => $listInters, 'nbPages' => $nbPages, 'page' => $page));
}
```

Now whenever i'm trying to access http://localhost:8000/ifsoc/

I get the error that the page doesn't exist, as if the default page 1 wasn't taken into account. Am I dumb ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: According to the url you posted you are using the prod environment. Have you tried clearing the prod cache or using the dev environment? localhost:8000/app_dev.php/ifsoc/

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately, both these solutions did not work.